# Second answer labeled as modification

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, front-page

[image: Screenshot of the Mi Yodeya front page, showing a question listed as "modified" by Double AA]

Only problem is, I didn't modify that top question; I answered it. FTR it was a second answer and I subsequently deleted my first answer, but still no modification to be heard of.

Comment: Somewhere else on the network (but I don't remember where), I saw "modified" show up when the action was the deletion of an answer.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Deletion does not bump?

Comment: Hmm, good point -- deletion isn't supposed to.  The other case I saw was like this one -- there was recent activity (bumping the post) and then a deletion.  I don't know if deletions are now bumping or there's just something funky with this combination of events.  (This may call for science.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status you see there relates to the whole thread (questions + answers). When an answer is deleted we don't bump the last activity date, we just set the last activity type as modified. We can't leave it with an `answered` status since this would allow for questions with 0 answers to have an answered status. Unfortunately history is tracked for each post (question/answer) separately, there is no global question timeline on record, so we can't simply pop to the last state, and computing it would be, too, a bit expensive (we'd have to read & compare all posts + their timelines to compute the correct state).